# Tkinter Checkbutton with flat checkbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

Basically what I want to have is a Checkbutton where the relief of the box sourrounding the check mark (or easier the indicator) is not sunken but rather flat. As an example of how it should look like: Take a look at the checkbuttons in (Windows-) menus. For those who don't know what I mean:

[image: windows menu checkbutton]

OS: Windows 10

Python 3.7

Comment: Are you asking about the `Checkbutton` widget, or a checkbutton on a menu?

Comment: I am asking about the actual Checkbutton widget. On a menus checkbutton this is (at least on windows 10) standard. ^^

Comment: Did you try `ttk.Checkbutton`?

Comment: @acw1668 Oh for sure. I completely forgot about ttk. Thanks man. Yeah there is a stylingoption -indicatorrelief ^^